# How to access nested key value pairs from an object in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a coherence cache object which holds a key value pair in such a way that the key value pair is like below

```
Key 
 - Value[Hash dictionary which has a key value pair as below]
        - Key
           - Value
```

My question is how do I get all the keys and values in C#.

Code:

```
string parent = ((Tangosol.Util.ConverterCollections.AbstractConverterCacheEntry)(cacheItem)).Key.ToString();
object child =  (((Tangosol.Util.ConverterCollections.AbstractConverterCacheEntry)(cacheItem)).Value);
object i = (((Tangosol.Util.Collections.HashDictionary)(((Tangosol.Util.ConverterCollections.AbstractConverterCacheEntry)(cacheItem)).Value)));
```

Comment: +  Entry {CacheEntry(Key = Binary(length=9,  Tangosol.Net.Cache.ICacheEntry {Tangosol.Net.Cache.CacheEntry}
  Key "EQEMEA" object {string}
-  Value Count = 3 object {Tangosol.Util.Collections.HashDictionary}
-  ["G44530607"] {object[1]} 
  Key "G44530607" object {string}
-  Value {object[1]} object {object[]}
  [0] "300" object {string}
-  ["G47546955"] {object[1]} 
  Key "G47546955" object {string}
-  Value {object[1]} object {object[]}
  [0] "500" object {string}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string root_str = ((ConverterCollections.AbstractConverterCacheEntry)         (cacheItem)).Key.ToString();
string parent_str = ((DictionaryEntry)(a)).Key.ToString();
string child_str = ((object[])(((DictionaryEntry)(a)).Value))[0].ToString();
```